How to "ignore": jakarta.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: No validator could be found for constraint 'jakarta.validation.constraints.Pattern'
I read that the usage of @jakarta.validation.constraints.Pattern should be used on return types of Charsequence. The issue that I am facing is that in my case, I am using generated java files from some gradle tasks that puts the Patterns on all getter methods, no matter the return type. At time of generation it is difficult to determine whether the return type is String or not, so the Pattern annotations are set on all the getter methods.
Now because we are working with a lot of dynamic data, we want to validate these inputs based on a flag validate.
When validate is set to true, I try to trigger validator.validate(view) which then throws jakarta.validation.UnexpectedTypeException:
ExampleService.kt:
import jakarta.validation.Validator
import com.example.generated.DEXPDF
// more imports

@Service
class ExampleService(
    // ...
    private val validator: Validator
)

// ... some code 

private fun assertRequestValid(view: DEXPDF) {
        val violations = validator.validate(view) // throws UnexpectedTypeException
        if (violations.isNotEmpty()) {
            throw ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, violations.joinToString(", "))
        }
    }

// ... some more code

The generated java looks something like that, this is just a small chunk of the file:
DEXPDF.java:
// some code...

@Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", comments = "JAXB RI v4.0.0", date = "2024-06-11T15:18:18+02:00")
    @Size(min = 1, max = 7)
    @JsonProperty("messageVersion")
    @Pattern(regexp = "F\\.[1-9][0-9]?\\.[1-9]?[0-9]")
    public String getMessageVersion() {
        return messageVersion;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the messageVersion property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", comments = "JAXB RI v4.0.0", date = "2024-06-11T15:18:18+02:00")
    public void setMessageVersion(String value) {
        this.messageVersion = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the messageSender property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link DEXPDF.MessageSender }
     *     
     */
    @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", comments = "JAXB RI v4.0.0", date = "2024-06-11T15:18:18+02:00")
    @Size(min = 1, max = 17)
    @JsonProperty("messageSender")
    @Pattern(regexp = "[A-Z]{2}[!-~]{1,15}")
    public DEXPDF.MessageSender getMessageSender() {
        return messageSender;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the messageSender property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link DEXPDF.MessageSender }
     *     
     */
    @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", comments = "JAXB RI v4.0.0", date = "2024-06-11T15:18:18+02:00")
    public void setMessageSender(DEXPDF.MessageSender value) {
        this.messageSender = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the messageRecipient property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link DEXPDF.MessageRecipient }
     *     
     */
    @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", comments = "JAXB RI v4.0.0", date = "2024-06-11T15:18:18+02:00")
    @JsonProperty("messageRecipient")
    @Pattern(regexp = "DE0[01][0-9]{4}")
    public DEXPDF.MessageRecipient getMessageRecipient() { // throws exception due to unexpected type
        return messageRecipient;
    }

// more code...

How can I tell the validator to just ignore the unexpected types instead of throwing an exception? If this is not configurable, is there an alternative?
I tried to surround it with a try catch which of course did not help at all. I also tried to create a custom factory by implementing the jakarta.validation.Validator but at that point I did not know how to continue, there wasn't a "straightforward" way to configure that.

I guess that in your case you should rather solve the root of the problem and find a way to generate your files without @Pattern annotations

Unfortunately, generating the files without Patterns is not an option. There are over a hundred generated java files that need to be individually and strictly validated based on the user input

Pattern doesn't work with Charset so not sure where you got this idea that that is needed. It is explicitly stated that @Pattern is only for CharSequence (https://jakarta.ee/specifications/bean-validation/3.0/apidocs/jakarta/validation/constraints/pattern). Trying to use it with other types will not work.

@M.Deinum that was a typo, I meant Charsequence. Stated in the javadocs: > The annotated CharSequence must match the specified regular expression

BUt you aren't using it on CharSequence type but on DEXPDF.MessageSender which isn't a CharSequence and others.

That's correct. As mentioned, these are generated files that I am trying to validate, so I would like to ignore or skip the ones that are not supported. I know it is not possible using the default configuration, I am looking for a solution or a workaround.

If that is the case, wouldn't ignoring the pattern on getMessageRecipient defeat the purpose of that annotation? I would assume DEXPDF.MessageRecipient to have a field that should actually be validated against that pattern and that the classes are generated incorrectly. Is the contract (XSD?) or binding file invalid, or maybe a plugin misbehaving? If all else fails, you could try to create custom ConstraintValidator implementations for the problematic classes and register these to work around that.

@KenS you are absolutely right. In my case both the binding files and the java files are generated based on XSDs. The Patterns seem to be indeed not in the right place.
